# Разработка Xml Parser

Tags: xml, xmlparser, java

Привет всем,

Можно ли из XML файла создать текстовый, потом эйтот файл текстовый передать системе CAT Tool, где это всё переведётся, а потом сгенерировать из переведённого текстового файла итоговый XML файл. Чтоб потом можно было сопоставив 2 файла в XML формате понять какой перевод у элемента с id=1 в начальном файле, соответствует id=1 в итоговом файле. Текстовый  файл создать, потому что во многих CAT Tool он читается.

XML File->Parse to .txt File->translate in CAT Tool(For Example: OmegaT, CafeTran)->Parse translated .txt File to XML File

можно ли это реализовать на Java, кто может подсказать, если да, то что для этого надо?

Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, например можно создать класс, описывающий объекты, с которыми Вы работаете. Далее сериализовать его с помощью JAXB. Получите XML. Это то, как можно создавать XML не сильно заморачиваясь.

Отвечая на Ваш вопрос: десериализуйте ваш xml файл с помощью того же JAXB, далее выведите все полученные объекты в текстовый файл. Скормите этот текстовый КАТу. Считайте новый текстовый, который выдаст КАТ. Сериализуйте.

Comment: Лично мне кажется, что задачу можно было бы решать по-другому(если бы детальнее описали, что требуется), но мой ответ отвечает непосредственно на ваш вопрос.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, надо придумать(создать) такой интерфэйс, кот. использовался бы, при внесении данных в CAT tool, там переведётся и выдаст итоговый файл, потом после перевода получив итоговый файл, сравнить его с исходным и ясно видеть, что к чему относится, как было выше написано с примером id. Т.е процесс перевода не затрагивается, только вот эта работа с входными и выходными данными.

Comment: Ну надо, так делай, в чем проблема то? Основные моменты я расписал. Не понятно только зачем использовать "сопоставление" именно XML-ников..

Comment: хорошо спс, просто так яснее и понятнее разобрать в конечном итоге перевод и исходный файл, т.е соотнести друг другу